# Avoid concurrency issues with consumer / producer classes

Tags: c#, concurrency, producer-consumer

So, I'm building an console application that has a List of objects.

- Every 1000ms, a "producer" is doing a HTTP request and creating a new object from the result, and adds it to the List of objects.
- Every 1000ms, a "consumer" is going analysing through all the objects in the list.
- Every 2000ms, another "consumer" is going analysing through all the objects in the list.
- Every 3500ms, another "consumer" is going analysing through all the objects in the list.

Once in a while, at arbitrary times, I want to ask one of the consumers what the result of this analysed data is.

So this sounds like a classic producer / consumer pattern. In JavaScript this wouldn't be a problem, since it's nonblocking. But how about C#? I would assume this could be quite a concurrency nightmare. As far as I can understand, this cannot be done simply with Tasks, since you cannot control whether it is running in the same thread context, or a new thread.

I'm looking for the "simplest" way to do accomplish the case above. I've looked into things like TPL Dataflow, also considered a pattern doing a simple "event loop" with deltatime (like in video games), what are your suggestions?

Best regards,

Comment: _"In JavaScript this wouldn't be a problem, since it's nonblocking"_ -- not sure what that means. "Nonblocking" doesn't imply "no problem". _"I would assume this could be quite a concurrency nightmare"_ -- done correctly, there should be no "nightmare". Done incorrectly, any type of concurrently operating algorithm can be a huge problem, JavaScript, C#, or any other language. _"this cannot be done simply with Tasks, since you cannot control whether it is running in the same thread context, or a new thread"_ -- why should "same thread context or a new thread" matter?

Comment: Use Rx.   Job done

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant nonblocking and singlethreaded. It might not be solution to all problems, but it surely is simpler without locks, deadlock issues, concurrency exceptions, etc (don't know if concurrency exception is a thing in C#, I'm used to Java). By "nightmare" I mean the complexity of concurrency as a topic, maybe wrong use of word :). I would like to avoid dealing directly with multithreading if possible, hence my question.

Rx looks interesting, thanks, I would give it a look :)

Comment: _"...I meant nonblocking and singlethreaded..."_ - impossible

Answer (score 1):

You can use a thead safe collection like the `BlockingCollection<T>` that implements interface `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`.

You can read more about thread safe collections [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/).